# sqlalchemy.exc.UnboundExecutionError: Table object 'responsibles' is not bound to an Engine or Connection

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to migrate a table with SQLAlchemy Migrate, but I'm getting this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.UnboundExecutionError: Table object 'responsibles' is not bound to an Engine or Connection.  Execution can not proceed without a database to execute against.
```

When I run:

```
python manage.py test
```

This is my migration file:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from migrate import *

meta = MetaData()

responsibles = Table(
    'responsibles', meta,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('breakdown_type', String(255)),
    Column('breakdown_name', String(500)),
    Column('email', String(255)),
    Column('name', String(255)),
)

def upgrade(migrate_engine):
    # Upgrade operations go here. Don't create your own engine; bind
    # migrate_engine to your metadata
    responsibles.create()

def downgrade(migrate_engine):
    # Operations to reverse the above upgrade go here.
    responsibles.drop()
```

Comment: see `Column('name', String(255)),` the extra comma at the end, it's because there are more columns?

Comment: no, it's the last one. But I removed it and I still get the same error.

Comment: did you create your engine? like this `engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')` and then do `meta.create_all(engine)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

did you create your engine? like this

`engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')`

and then do

`meta.bind = engine
meta.create_all(engine)`

Answer (score 6):

You need to supply `engine` or `connection`

[`sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData.bind`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData.bind)

For e.g.:

```
engine = create_engine("someurl://")
metadata.bind = engine
```