# Confused between engine metadata, Base and Sessions: sqlalchemy.exc.UnboundExecutionError

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am working with SQLAlchemy and I am getting confused between Engine, Metadata, Base, and Sessions.

I did find some useful links: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45045147/sqlalchemy-exc-unboundexecutionerror-table-object-responsibles-is-not-bound-t), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34322471/sqlalchemy-engine-connection-and-session-difference) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44098854/understanding-metadata-from-sqlalchemy-in-python), but I think it would help to know why the code below is not working.

```
import sqlalchemy as sqlalc
from sqlalchemy import Column, INTEGER, Integer,ForeignKey, Table, VARCHAR, TIMESTAMP, MetaData, create_engine, inspect, cast, select, SmallInteger
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

url = 'mysql://info@127.0.0.1/info'
engine = create_engine(url, echo=True)

metadata = MetaData()
metadata.bind = engine
metadata.create_all(engine)

connection = engine.connect()

Base = declarative_base()

Base.metadata.create_all()
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
```

When I execute, I get the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.UnboundExecutionError: MetaData object is not bound to an Engine or Connection.  Execution can not proceed without a database to execute against.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Definitions

- Engine: an abstraction for a database connection, or connection pool
- Metadata: an object that knows about database objects, primarily tables
- Base: the base class for ORM models
- Session: an object that keeps track of new, removed and changed ORM model instances while they are in use; it sends changes to the database (`Session.commit()`) or reverts them (`Session.rollback()`)

## Code

This code

```
metadata = MetaData()
metadata.bind = engine
metadata.create_all(engine)
```

"works" because you have *bound* (or associated) an engine with your [MetaData](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/metadata.html#working-with-database-metadata) instance: the engine enables connection to a database to create any tables that have been registered with the `MetaData` instance.  However you should be aware that binding like this is deprecated in SQLAlchemy v1.4.  The preferred approach is to pass the engine to `create_all` like this:

```
metadata = MetaData()
metadata.create_all(engine)
```

This code

```
Base = declarative_base()
Base.metadata.create_all()
```

does not work because there is no engine associated with `Base.metadata`. As before, the preferred approach is to pass an engine to `create_all`:

```
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

In both cases, executing `create_all` will do nothing unless tables have been registered with the metadata instances. For core, this usually happens through table definitions:

```
metadata = MetaData()
t = Table(
    't',
    metadata, # <- this will associate the table with the metadata
    Column(...),
)
```

In the ORM, (using declarative mapping), the association is made by  inheriting from `Base`:

```
Base = orm.declarative_base()


class MyModel(Base): # <- this will register mytable with Base's metadata
    __tablename__ = 'mytable'
    ...
```